# How to exclude certain rows in table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have reached the data I want from a table, but do not want the abbreviations between the individual player stats (Rk, Pos, Name, etc). How can I exclude those while keeping the wanted data? The rows that contain the abbreviations are classed as "thead" but I cannot figure out how to use that info to skip over it. I know the players' data is all compressed together, but for now I am focused on just printing the data I want and then picking it apart.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def main():
    # Url to scrape
    my_url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2019.shtml"
    # Opening url
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    # Parsing page
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    container = page_soup.find("div", id="div_team_batting")
    for player in container.find_all("tr"):
        print(player.text)
```

Output:

```
Rk
Pos
Name
Age
G
PA
AB
R
H
2B
3B
HR
RBI
SB
CS
BB
SO
BA
OBP
SLG
OPS
OPS+
TB
GDP
HBP
SH
SF
IBB

1CYasmani Grandal#30602442063258821436303450.282.381.544.92513811231031
21BJesus Aguilar2958183153132950423002343.190.294.301.595574681030
32BMike Moustakas*306026023644651402043302048.275.342.589.93113713984000
4SSOrlando Arcia24662502262958101828332350.257.324.416.740929470013
53BTravis Shaw*2945174150152650511002255.173.287.307.594564652002
6LFRyan Braun35612262092757901036411451.273.324.459.7841029652000
7CFLorenzo Cain33632882614166190427632145.253.313.372.684799773030
8RFChristian Yelich*2760263217527511225541413945.346.449.7601.209208165540312

Rk
Pos
Name
Age
G
PA
AB
R
H
2B
3B
HR
RBI
SB
CS
BB
SO
BA
OBP
SLG
OPS
OPS+
TB
GDP
HBP
SH
SF
IBB

91BEric Thames*3260172141273560826112760.248.378.461.8391196503011
10LFBen Gamel*2759169149233990416111649.262.343.403.746956003012
112BHernan Perez284812711918326051041835.269.315.445.760965340000
122BKeston Hiura (40-man)22176964818105910323.281.333.531.8651213402000
13CManny Pina3229625548202400516.145.242.291.533391612000
14UTJacob Nottingham (40-man)246551200140002.400.4001.0001.400247500000
15LFTyler Saladino (40-man)292220000000001.000.000.000.000-100000000

Rk
Pos
Name
Age
G
PA
AB
R
H
2B
3B
HR
RBI
SB
CS
BB
SO
BA
OBP
SLG
OPS
OPS+
TB
GDP
HBP
SH
SF
IBB

16PBrandon Woodruff*26163331110300400113.323.344.419.763991300100
17PZach Davies2614282713100100114.111.143.148.291-23400000
18PJhoulys Chacin (10-day IL)311116152300110016.200.250.400.65066600000
19PChase Anderson3111141400000000011.000.000.000.000-100000000
20PFreddy Peralta231013121200010005.167.167.167.333-12200100
21PGio Gonzalez (10-day IL)335970000000016.000.125.000.125-62000100
22PCorbin Burnes2417870200000002.286.286.286.57151200100
23PAdrian Houser2611220000000002.000.000.000.000-100000000
24PJunior Guerra3424220000000002.000.000.000.000-100000000
25PJosh Hader*2524110000000000.000.000.000.000-100000000
26PAaron Wilkerson (40-man)3031111001200001.0001.0004.0005.0001109400000
27PTaylor Williams# (40-man)277110000000001.000.000.000.000-100000000
28PBurch Smith (40-man)293110000000001.000.000.000.000-100000000
29PDonnie Hart* (40-man)284110000000000.000.000.000.000-100000000
30PJeremy Jeffress3119000000000000000000
31PAlex Claudio*2732000000000000000000
32PJay Jackson313000000000000000000
33PJimmy Nelson301000000000000000000
34PAlex Wilson3211000000000000000000
35PJake Petricka315000000000000000000
36PMatt Albers*3624000000000000000000
37PJacob Barnes2916000000000000000000
Team
Totals29.3672624231534058910951173364011259636.254.334.457.7921051059532741521
Rank in 15 NL teams26610121153146333288
Non-Pitcher     Totals29.5672494219333456810551153274011255573.259.341.469.8101091028532701521
Pitcher Totals27.067130122621402900463.172.198.254.453173100400

Rk
Pos
Name
Age
G
PA
AB
R
H
2B
3B
HR
RBI
SB
CS
BB
SO
BA
OBP
SLG
OPS
OPS+
TB
GDP
HBP
SH
SF
IBB
```

Comment: Hey Man, can be specific about what all data you need to scrape. e.g name, pos and what else?

Comment: Pretty much everything in that line. bharatk shows how to exclude certain data so I might leave out a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)-in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():

    my_url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2019.shtml"
    response = requests.get(my_url)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    container = page_soup.find("table", id="team_batting")
    tbody = container.find("tbody")
    data = []

    for tr in tbody.find_all("tr"):
        _class = tr.get("class")
        player = {}

        #skip table body header
        if _class is not None and "thead" == _class[0]:
            continue

        #scrape player details
        for td in tr.find_all("td"):
            player[td['data-stat']] = td.text.strip()

            """ if you want to exclude specific data add if condition like 
                
                if td['data-stat'] == "age":
                    player['age'] = td.text.strip()
                    
                    
                # you can find td['data-stat'] attribute details if you inspect in table row columns
             
            """

        data.append(player)

    print(data)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in line with your code, change selector to use :has, bs4 4.7.1. to check row has td elements within as this will exclude only th (table header) rows. I have also switched to selecting the table direct by id.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def main():
    # Url to scrape
    my_url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2019.shtml"
    # Opening url
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    # Parsing page
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    #if you want one row of headers uncomment next two lines:
    #headers = [th.text for th in page_soup.select("#team_batting tr:nth-of-type(1) th")][:-2]
    #print(headers)
    for player in page_soup.select("#team_batting tr:has(td)"):
        print(' '.join([i.text for i in player.select('th, td')]))
        #I have chosen to join to give nice line based output but you could simply do another loop for i in player.select...... to get long print out

main()
```

---

On a side note: You could grab tables with pandas and index into returned list to get nicely formatted tables of interest:

```
import pandas as pd

tables  = pd.read_html('https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2019.shtml')
#e.g.
print(tables[10])
```

---

If you wanted to construct your own dataframe:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

def main():
    # Url to scrape
    results = []
    my_url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2019.shtml"
    # Opening url
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    # Parsing page
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    headers = [th.text for th in page_soup.select("#team_batting tr:nth-of-type(1) th")][:-2]
    for player in page_soup.select("#team_batting tr:has(td)"):
        row = [i.text for i in player.select('th, td')]
        results.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
    print(df)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the variety of solutions. Regarding the dataframe solution at the very bottom, could you please explain what is happening in the line where the headers are being set? More specifically what "#team_batting tr:nth-of-type(1) th" and [:-2] is doing?

Comment: Will do. I think the above is likely more efficient so will write something up in the next few days. Remind me.

Comment: I appreciate your help. That "side note" you included has actually caught my eye now, because I was thinking about using some of those other tables on the site in the future if I were to expand on this independent learning project of mine. Might as well have everything on that page.

Comment: #team_batting is element with that Id. The next bit selects the headers in the first row and then sliced off the last empty headers.